# Empty pandas dataframe when querying from redshift using psycopg2

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2, pyspark, pandasql

I would like to read data from redshift table and load it to dataframe and perform transformations. I used `psycopg2` to connect to redshift and used pandas `read_sql` to query the table as below

```
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=sales host=redshifttest-xyz.cooqucvshoum.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com port=5439 user=master password=secret")
cur = con.cursor()
sql = "select * from dtw.rpt_account_transfer_hist where transfer_date>=2020-07-01;"
df  = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

I see an Empty Dataframe but data exist when I query the database. When I print the schema everything is **non-null object**.

I parameterized the **transfer_date** as below and tried again. This time the whole data set is returned without any filter being applied. Not sure where I'm missing. I tried cast in the sql query itself but it returned an empty dataframe. Any leads please.

```
curr_dt = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(3), '%Y-%m-%d')
sql = "select * from dtw.rpt_account_transfer_hist where transfer_date>=" +str(curr_dt)+";"
df  = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

The data in redshift table is like below with datatype as `varchar` for `col1`,`col2`,`col4`,`col5` and `date` for `transfer_date`.

```
col1    col2   transfer_date col4    col5
6052148 670018  2020-07-13  640033  6052148
5260969 640737  2020-07-11  640033  5260969
4778065 610050  2020-07-11  610017  4778065
7942224 690020  2020-07-11  690032  7942224
5260969 640737  2020-07-10  640033  5260969
4778065 610050  2020-07-10  610017  4778065
7942224 690020  2020-07-10  690032  7942224
5073022 640601  2020-07-09  640679  5073022
0309991 640601  2020-07-09  640729  0309991
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing single quotes around the date, try with this:

```
sql = "select * from dtw.rpt_account_transfer_hist where transfer_date>='2020-07-01';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit weird, I haven't changed anything and it started working.